# Root mean square error (RMSE) using R for the Boston Housing Data:

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I appreciate any form of idea or assistance you put into this.

I have presented with an assignment with the Boston Housing data.

The goal is to make a prediction using randomForest. 
The quantity to optimize is the RMSE.

I am confused as to how to go about the RMSE. Please help guys

Thanks

I have tried following the RMSE formula and I have gone through the basic idea but I am not making any progress. Please guide

Thanks

```
  raw.data <- read.csv("Boston Housing data.csv", header = T, sep = "")
  fit1<-lm(raw.data$MEDV~.,data = raw.data)
  RMSE<- sqrt(mean((raw.data-fit1)^2),na.strings="?")
```

> Error in Ops.data.frame(raw.data, fit1) : 
>          list of length 12 not meaningful

Comment: Very general, basic debugging tip. When you have an error in a line, run each of the pieces of that line to see what's there. With your line, you might start shrinking it to `mean((raw.data-fit1)^2)` to see if the problem is the `sqrt()`. You'll get the same error, so then you try `mean((raw.data-fit1)^2)`. Same error, so try `raw.data-fit1`, same error, so you look at `raw.data` and hopefully realize it's the *whole data frame*, which doesn't make sense. Then you change it to `raw.data$MEDV-fit1`. Still an error! Then look at `fit1`, and see it's a model, not a vector of numbers...

Comment: To succeed in learning R (or any computer language), the most important skill you can develop is debugging by isolating problems and checking your assumptions about what each little piece of code is.

Comment: Is there a reason to code the metric from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to subtract fitted values from the entire `raw.data` data frame. Updating your RMSE line should fix it:

```
RMSE<- sqrt(mean((raw.data$MEDV - fit1$fittedvalues)^2),na.strings="?")
```

Comment: In OP's code, `fit1` is the linear model object, not the fitted values. Also use `fit1$fittedvalues`, or you subtracting the linear model from the response column.